# Need more sounds... Cars and boats

Tags: career, sound-effects

We have a few shows ahead that need plenty of vehicles/cars and several boats.
We will do as much custom recording that we can but I'm not shure it will be enough still.

So, suggestions on sound effects with varied sounds of similar vehicle types from several angles and speeds.
We have most of the standard Major FX lib's.
Any costum libraries for stuff like this around?

We need regular (preferably European) cars and boats.
Race cars and sports boats aren't going to give us what we need.

Comment: hey, this is david @ tracktimeaudio. You might want to check with Greg Hill at Soundwave Concepts re: the boats, I know he's done some work with them before. Doing a good recording with them is really tough because water noise is WAY harder to reduce than wind noise in a car.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a car library, but I have a couple of tracks of a ratty Jeep here:
http://soundcloud.com/thefaderjockey/sets/sick-jeep

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find **here:**

[Pole position production](http://www.pole.se/sounds.asp)

[Pond5](http://www.pond5.com/)

[Audiomicro](http://www.audiomicro.com/)

[Audiojungle](http://audiojungle.net/)

Comment: Thanks but
Pole Position is race based and some "cool" vehicles, not the stuff I'm looking for.
The other sites to me looks like run of the mill "selling sound stuff" sites. I need (and will pay for) properly organized and recorded sounds. Searching websites is not time well spent imo.
I could spend the time recording something useful instead...

Comment: Im thinking several perspectives, same time recordings of INT/EXT for fast basic cutting. passes both stereo and pan follows, Arrives-aways, Tear outs and high speed breaking with and without ABS if possible. Cornering, parking maneuvers plus assorted sounds from the specific car model.
Proper recordings really...
Perhaps we should sell the ones we'll make on Tuesday...
Yes the recording date I have previously asked advice on SSD has been delayed until Tuesday, a long wait but soon i'll get done.
Two cars recorded over night (less disturbances).

Comment: And yes there will be more recordings done, but those will wait until it dries up on the roads fully. Post winter setting here...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the sounds at this link. They are downloadable sfx. You will have to search through a bit to find exactly what you are looking for, but chances are you will find a number of useful vehicle sound effects there. http://rocksuresoundz.com/store/transport/

Comment: Thats exactly what I wasn't looking for...
Non organized, not specified and just simple recordings of random stuff. I almost fell like voting you down as promoting/selling your own stuff in response to a question that is not anywhre close to what was asked for is pretty bad form imho.

Answer (score 0):

You could try http://www.stephanschutze.com/ which has a rather large selection of vehicle sounds if your in need of some fresh material.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try HartFX? They have both a [Racing Library](http://hartfx.net/libraries/my-hart-is-racing/) and a smaller free [Yamaha R1 library](http://hartfx.net/libraries/hart-pounding-r1-mini-library/).

As an addition, [David Nichols](http://www.tracktimeaudio.com) has a [Kickstarter project going](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/69968530/record-audio-of-a-car-via-dyno-for-use-in-racing-v):

I'm always on the lookout for new high quality independent libraries. Tbh I can't think of a single independent library with boat sounds. At least not organized with metadata and at least 96/24. I'll keep a lookout for you though.

I also now realized you're a fellow countryman. Inc hidden message in strange language:

Lycka till. Säg gärna till om du hittar något.

Comment: Swedish note:Tack! Kollade din webbsida, men hittade inget i vem vad du är egentligen. Blir ju lite nyfiken :).

Thanks all. It does look like this is stuff that we just have to record ourselves. Bots I can understand has a bit limited use, but cars?!

Comment: http://www.linkedin.com/in/reachground - reachground.se. So strange that you can't find what you want :/

Answer (score 0):

Boom has just made more cars available.
Anyone got it yet?

Comment: It's actually only on Pre-order right now, releases in July.  Although I'd be curious to find out more about it.